# Add new blank row to datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, insert

I have a `DataGridView` that has a `DataTable` as the `DataSource`. Now I want to insert a new empty row to the `DataGridView` and make it totally black (like a divider line). I have tried to copy one line and make it black with this:

```
Datagridview1.rows.insertcopies(2,2,1);
```

But I'm getting this error:

> rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

How can I keep the `DataGridView` the way she is and just insert a blank row?

**Clarification**:

I want to make a divider. I couldn't find any solution to do it so I thought to do a blank line and make it black. Using:

```
for(int i=0;i<datagridview1.Rows.Count-1;i++)
{
    if(datagridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].formattedvalue.ToString() != datagridview1.Rows[i+1].Cells[1].formattedvalue.ToString())
    {
        //here I need to make a divider.
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure that with WinForms there is an easy way. You may try to wrap your data bound items into some viewmodels, that may represent either a proper row or a separator and then handle data binding or separator row  repainting on appropriate events, but it is not an easy or a good-looking solution.

Comment: what does your DataSource look like? its a DataTable?

Comment: Badiparmagi. Yes i have a datatable that take her data from excel file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could add a blank row as a divider, this seems more like a hack to me. Instead, I would color the existing cell borders.

This actually took more effort than I expected - I thought it would be as easy as setting a color on the row divider, but evidently [that's not how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1459469/3773066).

But you can still paint it yourself by handling:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellPainting += DataGridView1_CellPainting;
```

Likewise, since your painting of the divider is dependent upon cell values, you'll want to handle:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += DataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
```

The idea is to check your condition (comparing a cell value in the desired column to the next cell value in that same column) and when needed, draw your divider for each cell in the row that needs the divider. When a cell value in the conditional column is changed its whole row should be invalidated to trigger every cell in the row to repaint. Likewise, the previous should be invalidated just in case it's condition to draw the divider has now changed too.

```
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        DataGridViewRow thisRow = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        DataGridViewRow nextRow = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1];

        if (thisRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString() != nextRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString())
        {
            e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

            Rectangle divider = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y + e.CellBounds.Height - 2, e.CellBounds.Width, 2);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, divider);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}

private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > 0)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.InvalidateRow(e.RowIndex - 1);
        }

        this.dataGridView1.InvalidateRow(e.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

[image: demonatration of dividers between rows]

Conversely, you could also do this with `RowPrePaint` instead of `CellPainting`, but then you end up with the following possibility:

[image: another demonstration]

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty much self explanatory, there's a workaround I can think of that might give you the end result, however it's really "ugly" and might disrupt the data in future manipulation, so I'm not sure I would recommend it.

```
DataRow empty = table.NewRow();
table.Rows.Add(empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new row in the DataTable and bind it again!
Something like

```
        DataRow rd = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();

        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(rd);

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```